# MySql Function Is not giving proper result

Tags: mysql

I have created mysql function as below

```
 DELIMITER $$
 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetProductIDFunc`$$
 CREATE FUNCTION `GetProductIDFunc`( countryid INT (10) )
     RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
 BEGIN
declare out_id VARCHAR;    

select country_percentage INTO out_id from country_markup where estatus = '1' AND `country_id` REGEXP '[[:<:]]countryid [[:>:]]' limit 1;    
RETURN out_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And I have called this function like as below
      SELECT GetProductIDFunc( 223 )
but it gave me NULL value instead of 7 which is my expected result value. 
Check sample data here for above result [link]  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6aa92

**Note:** IF i replace `'[[:<:]]countryid [[:>:]]'` with static value like `'[[:<:]]223 [[:>:]]'` than function return desire result.
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't substitute values of variables inside of strings. You can form the regular expression using `concat`, for example:

```
select country_percentage INTO out_id from country_markup 
where estatus = '1' AND `country_id` REGEXP concat('[[:<:]]',countryid,'[[:>:]]')
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton Friend.i acknowledge Your obligation.